# Informix alter/Update table information

Tags: sql, sql-update, informix

I am using an informix database, and want to change the value of displayed from 'N' to 'Y'...
I am running the following sql but seem to be getting a syntax error:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET displayed ='Y' 
WHERE flag= 'S' OR flag ='DEP' OR flag = 'WTD';
```

I am using or, because in all 3 cases i want the displayed to be Y.
Any help on correct syntax and how to update or alter the table in informix will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?  The syntax looks correct.

Comment: do you have any primary key or a common value for records which has `flag= 'S' or flag ='DEP' or flag = 'WTD'`?

Comment: The SQL looks OK. You could simplify it with `WHERE flag IN ('S','DEP','WTD')` but it's effectively the same thing. Is there an index or constraint that's being violated by this change perhaps? Could you update your question with the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to update the column if it contains all three values: 
`'S', 'DEP', 'WTD'`.

You can create a subquery to get the row that has all three values, eg.

```
UPDATE  tableName 
SET     displayed = 'Y'
FROM    tableName, 
        (
            SELECT  primary
            FROM    tableName
            WHERE   flag IN ('S', 'DEP', 'WTD')
            GROUP   BY primary
            HAVING  COUNT(flag) = 3
        ) b 
WHERE   tableName.primary = b.primary
```

just change the column `Primary` to the common row value within the group.

- [Informix Update with Join](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqltmst150.htm)

Comment: The cross-reference to the 'UPDATE with join' notation  is to a feature in the XPS (Extended Parallel Server), not in regular Informix (IDS — Informix Dynamic Server).  XPS is not formally end-of-life, but is not actively developed or widely used.  Using an UPDATE-with-join should be overkill anyway; the original query should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding your question, I tried something as follows and it worked for me, I didnt find any syntax error on Informix.

Following is what i tried

```
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME>
SET action='A'
WHERE action = 'I' OR action = 'U';"

Database selected.


57 row(s) updated.


Database closed.
```

So syntactically i found no error.

Can you share the syntax error that you get ?

Make sure that all the columns exists in the same table or use alias if they are in other table.

Using IN keyword is inefficient as compared to EXISTS

following alternative method:

```
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME>
SET action='A'
WHERE EXISTS
(    SELECT action 
     FROM <SAME_TABLE_NAME>
     WHERE action = 'I' OR action = 'U'
);
```

This is also tried and tested and worked for me.

Cheers.